# How to show and hide a simple <ol> list with onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, list, onclick, show

Considering the following paragraph and list:

```
<p id = "list1" onclick = "openList1()">List of Items</p>
<ol>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file1.txt">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file2.txt">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file3.txt">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file4.txt">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file5.txt">List Item 5</a></li>
</ol>
```

How can I show and hide this entire list with Javascript?

```
<script>
function openList1() {
...
}
</script>
```

I thank you for the attention!

Comment: Google "show and hide a div" and you'll see lots of ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give an id to the `OL` list.

```
<p id = "list1" onclick = "openList1()">List of Items</p>
<ol id="ollist">
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file1.txt">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file2.txt">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file3.txt">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file4.txt">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href = "/exampleFolder/file5.txt">List Item 5</a></li>
</ol>
```

And then in your javascript you can toggle it like this...

```
<script>
function openList1() {
    var list = document.getElementById("ollist");

    if (list.style.display == "none"){
        list.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        list.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName('ol');
myList[0].style.visibility = 'hidden'; // 'visible'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function openList1() {
$("ol").toggle();
}
</script>
```

Can you use JQuery? If so, try the above

Answer (score 1):

```
var ol = document.getElementByTagName('ol');
 ol.style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can modify your list:

```
<ol id="list" style="display: none;">
```

You can write a function to show:

```
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
// call function to show your list
showStuff("list");
```

To hide your element:

```
function hideStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}
// call function to hide your list
hideStuff("list");
```