# Why is last select option always shown, even when styled out

Tags: html, css, html-select

While answering another question I came across this weird bug. A quick search has not found an existing question, so here goes:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/93D3h/4/

```
<select>
    <option>Item1</option>
    <option>Item2</option>
    <option>Item3</option>
    <option class="hidden">Item4</option>
    <option class="hidden">Item5</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Q: Why is `Item5` always shown, even though it is styled as hidden? `Item4` is not visible. Note: I am testing this in the latest version of Chrome.

### Update:

Different people are getting different results on different browsers. The following (from answer below) works on Chrome but *not* on the latest IE (both Item4 and Item5 are shown):

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Turns out this problem has been hit before (no surprise): [How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css) but the surprising thing is that browsers **do not** support removing options with styling. Go figure!

Comment: it is not showing on my browser

Comment: Item4 is also visible in Chrome

Comment: works fine in latest chrome v 36

Comment: I see Item4 and item5 in lastest IE. Only 5 in Chrome V36.

Comment: @KheemaPandey For me all options are visible in Chrome 36

Comment: my chrome version - Version 36.0.1985.125 and it not showing item4 and item 5

Comment: really strange bug.. I checked in safari and thre Item4 and Item5 appearing..

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie on IE 11 using `visibility: hidden;` does not show item4 and item5

Comment: @RakeshShetty windows or OSX?

Comment: @David windows 7 64bit

Comment: FYI I am running Window 8/8.1 with Chrome 36 and IE 10 (not latest - sorry).

Comment: @RakeshShetty OK, in OSX they all show.

Comment: This is not really a new issue, people were facing this issue a long time.. see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Comment: @Kheema Pandey: Not an exact dupe, but one of those answers may certainly help... I cannot believe it is that hard to remove options from a select via styling :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling `OPTION` elements using CSS is not a reliable solution because user agents implement this very differently and non-standard. I wouldn’t call this a bug, because there is no `style` attribute definition in the specs for the `OPTION` element: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6

You could use the `disabled` property instead:

```
<select>
    <option>Item1</option>
    <option>Item2</option>
    <option>Item3</option>
    <option disabled>Item4</option>
    <option disabled>Item5</option>
</select>
```

And/or use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM. A pretty good start would be to target the `disabled` elements for semantic fallback:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('*[disabled]'), function(element) {
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/93D3h/15/

Or use jQuery: `$('[disabled]').remove()`

**Update:**
Based on the comments and the new requirements, I made a small toggle demo here using data attributes instead: http://jsfiddle.net/95Ed5/

Comment: That only greys them out. The original question I found this one only wanted them hidden: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115392/javascript-hide-show-items-in-dropdown-list/25115571#25115571

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The visual appearance of `disabled` is not enforced, but at least it’s semantic. I’m just referring to the specs here, If `disabled` is not an option for you, use DOM manipulation. CSS or inline styles are not standard and therefor unreliable, that’s my point.

Comment: Correct: Inline styling does not work either. According to question Kheema Pandey found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css this is a known flaw in browsers.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Exactly, but I wouldn’t call it a *flaw*, because the specs doesn’t include the `style` attribute for the `OPTION` element at all. So it’s basically up to each user agent to do their own implementation, wich also seems to have OS variations as well.

Comment: OK, if not a flaw I would call not being able to style `options` a *serious design deficiency* :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie maybe so but then you would have to blame the specs. Styling form controls in general has always been troublesome, and it doesn’t get easier with all the new emerging devices. I would stick to standars here, you really don’t want to mess with usability when it comes to forms.

Comment: The original bug came from answering this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115392/javascript-hide-show-items-in-dropdown-list Which needs the hidden items to be shown when a "more" option was clicked, but I will accept your updated answer as correct for this question (if nobody provides a better answer soon).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I made a demo with a toggle function here: http://jsfiddle.net/95Ed5/

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Designed to display or hide the element, including a frame around it and background. When you hide an element, although it is not displayed at a place that takes the element remains on him. If the intended output of different elements in the same place on the screen to bypass this feature should use absolute positioning, or use the property display.

Comment: Scratch that... IE still shows Item4 and Item5... This is the strangest thing

Comment: Turns out you cannot *style-out* `select` `option`s consistently across browsers. You need to dynamically alter the list content instead. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot (cross browser solution) would be to use jquery to store the hidden values. It can be done it regular javascript too.

```
var array = $(".hidden");
$(".hidden").remove();
```

And then when you need them you get them in `array`

**Update**

Here is the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/93D3h/16/
I added two buttons to show what you could do with the stored hidden values (add them back to the select, or remove them)

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer and provide a JSFiddle to demonstrate? You are actually very close to the best solution, but it needs explaining clearly.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Updated answer with a fiddle

Comment: +1 for the fiddle. Modifying the DOM is the correct solution. The original question I was answering when I found this problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115392/javascript-hide-show-items-in-dropdown-list/25115571#25115571 I must keep David's answer as the "answer" as he also added this type of functionality.